# C# converting CSV to XML Output

Tags: c#, xml, csv

so I know there are a couple of threads on this topic, however I have tried to implement the following code and keep getting error:

```
 using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\CSVOutput.csv");

XElement Xml  = new XElement("Part",
    from str in lines
    let columns = str.Split(',')
    select new XElement("New Part",
        new XElement("Manufacturer", columns[0]),
        new XElement("MPN", columns[1]),
        new XElement("Description", columns[2]),
        new XElement("Quantity on Hand ", columns[3]),
        new XElement("U/M", columns[4]),
        new XElement("Cost", columns[5])
    )
);

System.Save(@"C:\XMLOutputFile.xml");
```

The errors I'm getting are the following:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xEeP.png)

Am I missing an import statement or is something wrong with the syntax? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this your exact code? If so: You should have a namespace scope with a class in it. Then a method where this code will be placed in. In python one can just put blocks of code and it will run (which is nice) but C# isn't the same

Comment: I strongly advise you to learn the basics of C# before trying to write code to do this. You haven't declared a type to contain this code, or any methods - the error messages tell you all that. Learn the basics of how to declare a class, how to declare a method within the class etc... the more diligent you are about learning the core aspects of the language, the easier everything else will be.

Comment: This has so many problems on so many levels I don't know where to start. I suggest you first try a `hello world` application in C#.

Comment: Start with an introductory tutorial on C#.  You can't just copy/paste snippets of code from the internet and expect them all to work together.  There is a structure and context to the code you write, and you need to learn the basics of that structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, your code needs to be inside of a class and a method (within that class).

Here's a very simple class that contains a single Main method:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\CSVOutput.csv");

            XElement xml = new XElement("Part",
                from str in lines
                let columns = str.Split(',')
                select new XElement("New Part",
                    new XElement("Manufacturer", columns[0]),
                    new XElement("MPN", columns[1]),
                    new XElement("Description", columns[2]),
                    new XElement("Quantity on Hand ", columns[3]),
                    new XElement("U/M", columns[4]),
                    new XElement("Cost", columns[5])
                )
            );

            xml.Save(@"C:\XMLOutputFile.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Create a console application and paste this example into the generated Program class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code in a class.
I suggest that you use visual studio to create a new "console application" and pay attention to that structure in Program.cs

Comment: And inside a function

Comment: And a namespace